# Cannot upload image from $_FILES

Tags: php, upload

I am doing a simple image upload with PHP, which I have done 100 times before. This time it isn't working. I have both the /tmp and uploads directories set to chmod 777, I have chown'd the directories to apache, I have verified that the $_FILES array is populated:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadimage" id="uploadimage" />

[uploadimage] => Array(
    [name] => dilbert.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpkuJyyP
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 731602
)
```

Here's my code:

```
$response = array();
$response['path'] = '';
$response['success'] = false;
$response['error'] = '';

$targetDir = "../../../images/uploads/";
$filepath = $targetDir . $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'];

// here just for testing since it won't return below
$response['path'] = $filepath;

if(is_array($_FILES)) {
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'])) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'], $filepath)) {
            $response['success'] = true;
            $response['path'] = $targetDir . $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'];
        } else {
            $response['error'] = 'File could not be moved';
        }
    } else {
        $response['error'] = 'File not found';
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = 'Files array not found';
}
```

The error I am getting is the innermost one, "File could not be moved"
The path I am getting back in my AJAX call is correct, it should be domain.com/images/uploads/filename.jpg and it is...

I manually uploaded an image to the uploads directory, domain.com/images/uploads/1.jpg and then uploaded that image again witht he uploaded, and it resolves in the UI, because the image was already there, thus I know the path being passed back is accurate.

What else can I try? Images are not ending up in /tmp

Apache errors

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(../../../images/uploads/dilbert.jpg):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/var/www/webapp/application/controllers/DocumentController.php 
on line 75, referer: http://192.168.1.3/document/

PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpm4Ivrx' to 
'../../../images/uploads/dilbert.jpg' in 
/var/www/webapp/application/controllers/DocumentController.php
on line 75, referer: http://192.168.1.3/document/

File does not exist: 
/var/www/webapp/public/images/uploads/dilbert.jpg, referer: 
http://192.168.1.3/document/
```

Comment: have you use <form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form> for uploading images?

Comment: Yup same as always

Comment: A few years late but since the `DocumentController.php` resides in `/var/www/webapp/application/controllers` your current `../../../images/uploads/` would evaluate to `/var/www/images/uploads/`. Which would explain the *"no such directory"* error and *"File does not exist: 
/var/www/webapp/public/images/uploads/dilbert.jpg"* error. Shouldn't it be `$targetDir = dirname(__DIR__, 2) . '/public/images/uploads/';` or `$targetDir =
 '../../public/images/uploads/';` to return `/var/www/webapp/public/images/uploads/` https://3v4l.org/5lCkI